# What is the proper format for setting TimeZones in iOS ?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimezone

I've tried using this [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) to get the appropriate abbreviation for time zones to use in:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = formatString
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: setZone)
```

and "GMT" works as does "GST", but for some reason a good portion of the abbreviations do not work (for example GYT). Is there some other format that I should be using ? I have also tried passing in UTC-X also but that didn't work either

Comment: Use the `NSTimeZone` initializer that takes `forSecondsFromGMT`.

Comment: As I understand NSTimeZone forSecondsFromGMT would require calculation of the offset overtime I want to change the displayed timezone (which happens frequently in this app) is that correct IE .. GMT +6 would = 60*6 = 360 seconds [NSTimeZone forSeecondsFromGMT:360]

Comment: That would be minutes. GMT+6 means 6 hours. So that's 6*60*60 seconds.

Comment: :) Yeah sorry... This what I get for posting while half paying attention to am meeting :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is function I call from a NSTimer...

```
self.clock = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateClock), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func updateClock() {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        let date = NSDate();
        // "Apr 1, 2015, 8:53 AM" <-- local without seconds

        var formatter = NSDateFormatter();
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

        _ = formatter.stringFromDate(date);
                    // "2015-04-01 08:52:00 -0400" <-- same date, local, but with seconds
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "CET");
        let cetTimeZoneStr = formatter.stringFromDate(date);
        // "2015-04-01 12:52:00 +0000" <-- same date, now in UTC

        self.timer.text = cetTimeZoneStr


    }
}
```

And here some code to get the timezones known to the system!

```
let blah = NSTimeZone.knownTimeZoneNames()
let blah2 = NSTimeZone.abbreviationDictionary()
print("\(blah) \(blah2)")
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: rmaddy, I reread the question; answered too quickly felt guilty, did some googling and found the answer, which I added to my answer :)

Comment: I appreciate it - I used the abbreviationDict rather then the .plist I had created. Thanks